# Handle error of Unresponsive script by Javascript or C# code

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I had a Web Project, which sometime display popups like :

[image: >]

I am trying to block these popups by C# code or javascript.

Comment: Do you have any output in the Javascript console ? What's the code source of mutation-summary.js around line 575 ?

Comment: You can't block those messages, they're created by the browser and Javascript can't interact with these popups. But you can move the long running code to a web worker and then the page will not block and the message will not appear.

Comment: @AxelGuilmin, actually in my project there is no "mutation-summary.js" script. So i don't know what i do to fix this. And in console, there are some errors but not realated to "mutation-summary.js" script

Comment: @Gusman okay but how can i ? can you please show me some code for this. cause i tried lot of things like "WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;" but it doesn't work for me

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @Gusman thank you for help  ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is being caused by files in extensions for firefox. As may be the case it might be skype extensions. To disable extension in firefox, navigate to open menu button in firefox [image: see pic]

Click on the button then go to Add-ons then Extensions. Disable or remove skype and other unwanted extensions.

Comment: sir, this is good idea but we have to handle this problem with javascript code or any other code not with mannul settings.